# How to access a Java constant imported in JSP file into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Is the below syntax right,

```
var str = "<%= TestJS.other %>";
```

Say i have constant declared in TestJS.java file as below,

```
public static final String other = "OTHER";
```

Now i import it in a JSP file as below,

```
<%@page import="com.rohit.jsp.testing.TestJS" %>
```

And then in the same JSP file, i have a script tag in which i want to access the other JAVA constant.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myMethod1(){
        var str = "<%= TestJS.other %>"; 
        alert(str);
    }
</script>
```

Will this work as the double quotes in the str variable in javascript are of different color when i save it.

Comment: Please somebody answer...Edited the question as by mistake i had written semicolons instead of double quotes in the last line. Just wanted to know whether this syntax var str = "<%= TestJS.other %>"; is right. Not able to test it. Thats why asked the question.

Comment: This should work, with or without the quotes. Have you tested it? If it doesn't work try removing the quotes.

Comment: @mohammedkhan - Thanks for the answer.